# Spring webflux: how to send the flux error to the client

Tags: java, rest, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a basic REST controller that returns a Flux which might raise an error:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/foo", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Flux<Long> foo() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).map(t -> 1/(3-t)).take(4);
  }
```

and a webclient consumer:

```
webClient.get()
         .uri("/foo")
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToFlux(Integer.class)
         .doOnError(System.err::println)
         .doOnNext(System.out::println)
         .blockLast();
```

We can see that the server will send 0 -> 0 -> 1 (Similarly the client runs doOnNext for each one of them), but then the server throws an exception

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation

And the client doesn't detect the flux error (not running doOnError), instead it simply reads onComplete on the flux.
How to make the client run **doOnError** when the server-side flux emits an error?

Comment: Did you try to use something like that .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new NameRequiredException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "username is required", e))), String.class);

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about what you expect should be happening at the HTTP level? i.e. what should be the content of the SSE stream when this error happens?